# TypeError cloudinary is not a function

Tags: node.js

I dont know what Im doing wrong, I use the same code for another project and I did not have any problem with cloudinary

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const cloudinaryStorage = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const multer = require('multer');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
});

var storage = cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  folder: 'recipe',
  allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png'],
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const uploadCloud = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = uploadCloud;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to solve this issue.

```js
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
 
const app = express();
 
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    folder: 'some-folder-name',
    format: async (req, file) => 'png', // supports promises as well
    public_id: (req, file) => 'computed-filename-using-request',
  },
});
```